# Changing aesthetics in ggplot generated by svars package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm using the `svars` package to generate some IRF plots. The plots are rendered using `ggplot2`, however I need some help with changing some of the aesthetics.

Is there any way I can change the fill and alpha of the shaded confidence bands, as well as the color of the solid line? I know in `ggplot2` you can pass `fill` and `alpha` arguments to `geom_ribbon` (and `col` to `geom_line`), just unsure of how to do the same within the `plot` function of this package's source code.

```
# Load Dataset and packages
library(tidyverse)
library(svars)
data(USA)

# Create SVAR Model
var.model <- vars::VAR(USA, lag.max = 10, ic = "AIC" )
svar.model <- id.chol(var.model)

# Wild Bootstrap

cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1
boot.svar <- wild.boot(svar.model, n.ahead = 30, nboot = 500, nc = cores)

# Plot the IRFs

plot(boot.svar)
```

[image]

I'm also looking at the command for a historical decomposition plot (see below). Is there any way I could omit the first two facets and plot only the bottom three lines on the same facet?

```
hist.decomp <- hd(svar.model, series = 1)
plot(hist.decomp)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first desired result is easily achieved by resetting the `aes_params` after calling `plot`. For your second goal. There is probably an approach to manipulate the `ggplot` object. Instead my approach below constructs the plot from scratch. Basically I copy and pasted the data wrangling code from `vars:::plot.hd` and filtered the prepared dataset for the desired series:

```r
# Plot the IRFs

p <- plot(boot.svar)

p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$fill <- "pink"
p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$alpha <- .5
p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$colour <- "green"
p
```

[image]

```r
# Helper to convert to long dataframe. Source: svars:::plot.hd
hd2PlotData <- function(x) {
  PlotData <- as.data.frame(x$hidec)
  if (inherits(x$hidec, "ts")) {
    tsStructure = attr(x$hidec, which = "tsp")
    PlotData$Index <- seq(from = tsStructure[1], to = tsStructure[2], 
                          by = 1/tsStructure[3])
    PlotData$Index <- as.Date(yearmon(PlotData$Index))
  }
  else {
    PlotData$Index <- 1:nrow(PlotData)
    PlotData$V1 <- NULL
  }
  dat <- reshape2::melt(PlotData, id = "Index")
  dat
}

hist.decomp <- hd(svar.model, series = 1)

dat <- hd2PlotData(hist.decomp)

dat %>% 
  filter(grepl("^Cum", variable)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Index, y = value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("Time") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**EDIT** One approach to change the facet labels is via a custom `labeller` function. For a different approach which changes the facet labels via the data see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65814940/how-to-change-facet-labels-in-ggplot-image-generated-with-the-svars-package):

```r
myvec <- LETTERS[1:9]

mylabel <- function(labels, multi_line = TRUE) {
  data.frame(variable = labels) 
}
p + facet_wrap(~variable, labeller = my_labeller(my_labels))
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan , this solution works for me! One more question, is there a way to pass a vector of labels to relabel the facet titles in my first plot?

Comment: Hi Tanga. I just made an edit with one approach to achieve this as well as a link to a second approach.

Comment: Perfect solution @stefan, thanks so much for the help!!