# How to change facet labels in ggplot image generated with the svars package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using a sample of this dataset below (`data`) to create an SVAR model using the `svars` package

```
data <- structure(c(-1.87308398729904, 2.290631067509, 0.993462708465565, 
-1.29041209029221, 1.12545485962681, -2.636526517961, 1.64791593479841, 
-0.127800586695059, -0.649131035554795, -1.41838122120497, -0.0727559182898574, 
2.61173864035165, 0.408195006166245, 2.14851460203356, -3.43206431417578, 
-3.21097438990066, -0.633222142832857, 3.62032490350241, -1.88466472673507, 
3.1882672460176, -6.25889275693812, -5.63387155573629, -2.47686181080518, 
-0.00946230989793406, 1.15917422619178, 1.26429447879497, 0.986332225049047, 
2.41168238340004, 1.84115722165812, 1.41639006961984, 1.35342674612451, 
2.79543996486087, 0.605266622518563, 0.554959915380682, 1.07421168196309, 
1.2403520539725, 0.862800885835391, 1.26464488451186, 1.75852063191533, 
0.546966935763926, 0.534163056633208, 0.63109068920264, 0.935286647736344, 
0.159975810472712, 0.208743967794067, 0.973862299523898), .Dim = c(23L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("GDP", "CPI")), index = structure(c(1420070400, 
1427846400, 1435708800, 1443657600, 1451606400, 1459468800, 1467331200, 
1475280000, 1483228800, 1491004800, 1498867200, 1506816000, 1514764800, 
1522540800, 1530403200, 1538352000, 1546300800, 1554076800, 1561939200, 
1569888000, 1577836800, 1585699200, 1593561600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

Here is the code I've used. I'm looking for the easiest way to change the facet titles, is there a way to pass through a vector of new titles in the plot command. I know that typically you would pass
`` facet_wrap(~.,labeller = as_labeller(c(`old title names` = "new title names") `` when rendering a standard ggplot, I'm just unsure of how I can replicate that in my example.

```
# Load Packages
pacman::p_load(vars, svars, tidyverse)

# Create VAR Model

var.model <- vars::VAR(data, p=1, type = 'both', season=NULL)

# Crete SVAR Model using Cholesky Decomposition

svar.model <- id.chol(var.model)

# Bootstrap and plot

cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1

boot.svar <- wild.boot(svar.model, design = "fixed",
                            distr = "rademacher", nboot = 1000, n.ahead = 15,
                            nc = cores)

plot(boot.svar)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we review the [source](https://rdrr.io/cran/svars/src/R/plot.sboot.R) for the `plot` method for objects of class `sboot`, we'll see that the labels come from the column names of the data.frame in `x$true[[1]]`.

So, it's kind of a hack, but very effective to just change the names:

```
colnames(boot.svar$true[[1]]) <- c("V1","A","B","C","D")
plot(boot.svar)
```

[image]